# facebook's scribe queue issues

Tags: facebook, ssh-tunnel, facebook-scribe

we use scribe like this:

- Web server(SA) --->Local Scribe Server(SB)

  - Web server(SA) and Local Scribe Server(SB) on one machine;
  - The Web Server just send every log to scribe at most 3 times, after retry 2 times we just discard them.
  - The Local Scribe Server use a buffer store, the primary use a network store send logs to the next  Collector Scribe BJ and the secondary write the log to the local disk, and we set max_queue_size=1000000000 and max_queue_length=20000000.
- ---->Collector Scribe BJ(SC)----ssh tunnel(gzip compressed)---vpn--->Collector Scribe SH(SD)

  - Collector Scribe BJ(SC) and Local Scribe Server(SB) on one LAN.
  - The Collector Scribe BJ(SC) use a multi store, the store0 use a buffer store, the store0 primary use a network store send logs to the next  Collector Scribe SH and the store0 secondary write the log to the local disk, and we set max_queue_size=10000000 and max_queue_length=2000000.
  - The Collector Scribe BJ(SC) use the store0 -- buffer store -- primary store network send logs to a local port, and via the ssh tunnel send the messages from IDC BJ to IDC SH.
  - At last the collector scribe SH(SD) use a std file store write the logs to its disk.

Here is my questions.

- Question 1:
  I can't find max_queue_length option usage in the scribe source code. And also I find some infos mentioned in the googlegroup that max_queue_length is deprecated. So it is nothing effective here using "max_queue_length=20000000"?
- Question 2:
  Just the option max_queue_length "if the number of messages in the queue exceeds this value, the buffer store will switch to writing to the secondary store(described in the githup wiki)" can control when a buffer store scribe can switch the primary store to the secondary store. When max_queue_length is useless, how can I control the buffer store switch the primary stoe to the secondary store?
- Question 3:
  When Local Scribe Server(SB)  secondary store's write speed is greater than Web server(SA)'s input speed, anyhow Local Scribe Server(SB) will not lose data?
- Question 4:
  I also find a graph in the googlegroup that inder.pall mentioned. Here
  is the link: http://scribe-server.googlegroups.com/attach/979f9ffbe00f5eb3/Screen+Shot+2011-11-22+at+9.12.32+AM.png?gda=FIJ3I0cAAACFwDSo_bUG96Wo0CVG6AlpKMzYsToU_WRZEGbv_RKdbkT0wWvVm1xmkWqWMWNxOm4bQwFxJw55cVwemAxM-EWmeV4duv6pDMGhhhZdjQlNAw&view=1&part=4 
  I think just when the scribe is not available(not alive&timeout) or its queue size is greater than the max_queue_size, it will return TRY_LATER to its upriver scribe. At this time its upriver scribe will backup the messages to secondary?
- Question 5:
  As Question 4 mentioned, When the vpn(BJ--SH) is very busy and the lag is very large, but the tunnel is available and collector scribe SH(SD) not return TRY_LATER and clearly that the Collector Scribe BJ(SC)'s input speed is greater than its output speed into the tunnel, so the Collector Scribe BJ(SC)'s mem will continuous increase and not use the secondary store?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with same/similar questions last month. Thanks to the folks out there using scribe, I have found some of the answers:

1. So it is nothing effective here using "max_queue_length=20000000"?
   Answer: You are correct max_queue_length is depricated, and nothing else replaces the functionality. max_queue_length in my opinion hold more importance then is visible at first glance. For example: max_queue_length can help trottle and prevent TRY_AGAIN(s) which are caused when the input buffers(of scribe server) are full. If you want you can revert the changes that took max_queue_length out of scribe code. Here is the changeset: https://github.com/facebook/scribe/commit/1b5d5c89a40c737ed7fa9a028f490bf336cd0da8
2. When max_queue_length is useless, how can I control the buffer store switch the primary stoe to the secondary store?
   Answer: You'll wait until the primary store sends errors (EAGAIN - out of resouce) or TRY AGAIN, or max_queue_size of your scribe server has reached, and then you start writing to your secondary store. In this case the primary store connection goes to DISCONNECTED start. Once the connection is re-established (based in retry_interval and retry_interval_range) messages from secondary store will be 'replayed' to primary store.

3.When Local Scribe Server(SB) secondary store's write speed is greater than Web server(SA)'s input speed, anyhow Local Scribe Server(SB) will not lose data?
Answer: I guess not, unless you have async-appenders writing to the scribe server somewhere or the secondary storage is a disk which is full! ... or your scribe server crashes, in which case i'll eat up messages equal to the max_size.

1. ...TRY_LATER to its upriver scribe. At this time its upriver scribe will backup the messages to secondary?
   Answer: Yes. As I mentioned in answer to your fist question.
2. ...the Collector Scribe BJ(SC)'s mem will continuous increase and not use the secondary store?
   Answer: I guess, you have guessed the answer by now. In this scenerio your scribe server will send a TRY_AGAIN upstream and expect appenders writing to it will throttle their write speed.

Also you may find this helpful: http://groups.google.com/group/scribe-server/browse_thread/thread/ec2b1b641a968c0b

-Abhinav